# Copy Formatting from another sheets and perform calculations using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, calculation

First Off, I would like to thank you in advance for any help you may offer. I have a workbook, which performs financial calculations. I have a model sheet that performs calculations with formatted cells. I formatted the required cells on a sheet called "MISC", which contains only the required formatting. I am attempting to copy this after the last column, once copied add the appropriate calculations to the copied cells in this last column. I would like to continue running the macro as required, copying the formatting from Misc and adding the calculations one after the next as needed. However, I am copying the formatting and adding the calculations, but it's requiring the macro to run twice. Is there a way to perform this operation by only running the macro once? Thanks, please see my code below:

```
Sub Model2()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim lastCol2 As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Continue As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MODEL 2")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MISC")
    
    Contine = True
    lastCol = ws.Cells(29, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column
    lastCol2 = ws.Cells(31, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If ws.Range("C29").Value <> "" Then
        ws2.Select
        ws2.Range("A1:B39").Copy
        ws.Select
        ws.Cells(29, lastCol).PasteSpecial
        Continue = True
    If Continue Then
        ws.Cells(29, lastCol2).Value = ws.Cells(29, 3).Value
        ws.Cells(54, lastCol2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-22]C:R[-2]C)"
    End If
    Else
        MsgBox "You must enter all data in yellow fields to perform calculations, please verify all necessary inputs are filled.", vbOKOnly
    Continue = False
    End If
    
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What's varible `Continue` for? `Continue = True   If Continue Then [code] ` doesn't make any sences. Code will be executed everytime.  btw, please don't VBA keyword (`Continue`) as variable name.

Comment: Honestly, it's not really serving much purpose; I thought it might allow the code to perform copy and then execute calculation, however it doesn't work. The macro copies the formatting, but will not perform the calculation unless it's executed a second time. Thanks for pointing this out in the future I will not use this.

Comment: What does `not perform the calculation' mean? Does the cells have formula after the first run?

Comment: The formatted cells copy over with no formulas. If you run the macro a second time the formulas populate.

Comment: Remove `Contine = True` `If Continue Then` `End If (before Else)`and run your code.